# Is there a more elegant way to read four bytes from a ByteBuffer and treat each byte as a char

Tags: java, nio

Is there a more elegant way to read four bytes from a ByteBuffer and treat each byte as a char (rather than each pair as a char) then this, Im sure there must be a more succint way.

```
public static String read4Chars(ByteBuffer bytes) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            char ch = (char) bytes.get();
            sbuf.append(ch);
        }
        return sbuf.toString();
    }
```

Comment: no each byte represents an ASCII character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegance is quite subjective. You could try that:

```
public static String read4Chars(ByteBuffer bytes) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    bytes.get(b);
    return new String(b, Charset.forName("ASCII"));
}
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine, it doesn't break the side effect of consuming bytes from the buffer, I'd just add that you should add the charset in the constructor of the string: `new String(b, Charset.forName("ASCII"))` just to make sure that the result is ASCII and not the default charset

Comment: @morgano you are right about the charset. One should not assume the platform default charset respects ASCII :)

Comment: @dotnov thx that is better, and if i started with a byte[] parameter then would be alot better, unfortunately ive been trying to move away from byte arrays to ByteBuffers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to "consume" the bytes from the buffer, you coud try:

```
public static String read4Chars(ByteBuffer bytes) throws IOException {
    byte[] array = bytes.array();
    return String.valueOf((char) array[0])
        + (char) array[0] + (char) array[0] + (char) array[0];
}
```